# Maxwell Coexistence from Entropy Considerations

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

As explained by [Maxwell, (1875)](https://doi.org/10.1038/011357a0), a realistic thermodynamical system will, at low temperature, have pressure vs. volume curve that is non-monotonic. In practice, though, the observable states of the system will lie along a straight line of constant pressure, where part of the system is in the condensed liquid state and part of the state is in the gas state (see picture from Wikipedia below). The pressure on the straight line corresponds to the maximum pressure of the gas and the minimum pressure of the liquid. As further explained by Maxwell, this pressure can be determined by requiring that the areas above and below the line be equal.

Although the equal area law is necessarily correct as a consistency condition, it does not explain physically what is going on, i.e. what the fluid is doing. After all, the fluid is not sweeping out the PV curve or calculating integrals. I would like there to be some entropic (or other) argument to explain the coexistence pressure $P_{\rm e}$. For example, an argument that a system which is partly in the liquid phase and partly in the gas phase has more entropy than a homogeneous system, and where this maximally entropic pressure agrees with Maxwell's area law.

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_construction]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vapor and liquid phase coexist along the straight line. Call the left and right intersection with the original curve $v_A$ and $v_B$ and the vapor pressure $p_v$.

Coexistence implies the equality of chemical potentials between the phases. Because if the phases were at different chemical potentials, particles would flow (i.e condensate/vaporize) from one phase to the other until equilibrium is reached.

At constant temperature, chemical potential is the same as Gibbs' free energy $g = f + pv$, where $f$ is Helmholtz' free energy. This implies $f_A-f_B = p_v(v_B-v_A) $

On the other hand, $f_A - f_B = \int_B^A \partial_v|_T f\,dv = \int p dv = p_v(v_B-v_A) - \text{area under} + \text{area over}$ establishing the result.

In the end it is an entropic argument, because all thermodynamic potentials derive from the entropy.

Comment: Sorry for unselecting, I'm still confused... Why should the state of the system depend on the shape of an inaccessible curve? Why can't I answer the question using only the physical part of the curve (A-B-C and E-F-G in Maxwell's paper)?